# Using Google Analytics on a website hosted in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, google-analytics, azure-web-app-service

To apologize upfront -- I am not a coder and have zero knowledge of coding, I am merely someone who really wants to use Google Analytics for a website hosted from Microsoft Azure.

**Goal:** analyze access data and create easily viewed, detailed reports of it of a website hosted on Microsoft Azure

**Current idea for the method:** Google Analytics (via SSH?)

**Status:**

- The website is hosted in a server in Japan
- I am an owner of the web app and the website is uploaded on in Microsoft Azure
- I have been advised to log on to Azure portal, then remote connect web service via SSH console
- No one in company seems to know how to do anything further than this
- I cannot find any how-to online about how to achieve the above goal

Can anyone help me by advising 1)whether this is possible with Google Analytics, 2) whether there is another easier method, or 3) if it is impossible in the first place?

Thank you in advance,

Regards,

Roselle

Comment: You can use the Google Analytics API as described in this [blog post](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/) and see if that helps.
Also, you can analyze the data through Azure Application Insights feature.
Take a look at App Insights service: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/application-insights/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to add Google Analytics JavaScript references to the website like you can any website.

If you are looking for page analytics like (user visits, top pages, etc.) that should all be handled by adding Google Analytics script references to your website. (Typically in a base template or etc.)

I am guessing that if you are remote connecting via SSH that the website is hosted on an Azure VM running a Linux distribution.   So it seems they are suggesting that you tunnel into the machine with SSH and then load the changes necessary (copying files or editing files) to add the script references to activate Google Analytics.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will confirm with website vendor and work towards a solution!